# Is creating a constant or enum class for template page efficient?

Tags: php, enums

Basically I'm building a website that need a html like template called from the folder using their file name.

Should I use a enum/constant class or should I just call them straight to their filename?

Example:

```
abstract class ViewTemplate
{

    const ORDER_HISTORY         = 'order_history_template.html';
    const PURCHASE_HISTORY      = 'purchase_history_template.html';
    //etc...
}
```

Is this kind of class necessary and do they hog a lot of resources if I call the class when I have a lot of template?

Comment: I believe you'd be better off determining the view you wish to use in the controller, something like `$this->render('template_name'`)`. It makes more sense semantically and logically. It's pretty redundant to define/const a template name since they're not something that are required to be constants.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the filename is a unique identifier - unless you expect the file names to change in the future (which isn't likely, and even if it happens refactoring is simple) there is no point to it.

You already have a unique identifier for a file you're loading. The only benefit of passing an enumeration with properties here is type-safety but you're only calling it once anyway so a typo could happen in one place anyway.

So overall it's redundant.

Comment: Yeah, I guess you are right.